# Migrating a small gtk3 sample from gtk 3.18 to gtk 3.22

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I am working on some application, where we draw widgets like "RadioButton", "CheckButton" etc. by calling "gtk_render_option", "gtk_render_check" and so forth. Our application works fine on gtk 3.18, but on gtk 3.22, the widgets are not drawn correctly. I have gone through the changes made in themes in 3.20 and tried to make some changes in my application, but I am not able to understand what I need to do exactly.

I have created a small sample where I draw "RadioButton" using the gtk_render_option API. This works fine for me in gtk-3.18, but the causes issue in gtk 3.22. I am attaching images and code for reference. It would be great if someone here can guide me on "How can I make this small demo work on gtk 3.22". I should be able to take care of the rest myself. I can provide any further information required.

Note: I have tried both "radio" and "radiobutton" in gtk_style_context_add_class API. Both don't work for me.

**Output with gtk 3.18**

[image: "gtk 3.18"]

**Output with gtk 3.22**

[image: gtk 3.22]

**Code**

```
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean
draw_cb_options (GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr)
{
  GtkStyleContext *context;

  context = gtk_widget_get_style_context (widget);

  gtk_style_context_save (context);

  gtk_style_context_add_class (context, "radio");
  gtk_style_context_set_state (context, 0);
  gtk_render_option (context, cr, 10, 50, 40, 40);
  gtk_style_context_set_state (context, GTK_STATE_FLAG_CHECKED);
  gtk_render_option (context, cr, 70, 50, 40, 40);
  gtk_style_context_set_state (context, GTK_STATE_FLAG_INCONSISTENT);
  gtk_render_option (context, cr, 120, 50, 40, 40);
  gtk_style_context_set_state (context, GTK_STATE_FLAG_INSENSITIVE);
  gtk_render_option (context, cr, 170, 50, 40, 40);

  gtk_style_context_restore (context);

  return TRUE;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkStyleContext *context;
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  g_signal_connect (window, "draw", G_CALLBACK (draw_cb_options), NULL);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);

  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [GTK+ 3.20 changelog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch32s10.html):

> GtkDrawingArea used to implicitly render the theme background before calling the ::draw handler. This is no longer the case. If you rely on having a theme-provided background, call `gtk_render_background()` from your ::draw handler.

Even calling `gtk_render_background` in the draw function made no difference. The sample below is based on gtk3-demo's [foreign draw](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/69ddfcf1ed165eb9b092f4da8a4b7396290487b0/demos/gtk-demo/foreigndrawing.c), I tried my best to simplify but still it has to go through a lot to accomplish what you need.

[image: sample screenshot]

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>

static GtkStyleContext *
get_style (GtkStyleContext *parent,
           const char      *selector)
{
  GtkWidgetPath *path;
  GtkStyleContext *context;

  if (parent)
    path = gtk_widget_path_copy (gtk_style_context_get_path (parent));
  else
    path = gtk_widget_path_new ();

  gtk_widget_path_append_type (path, G_TYPE_NONE);
  gtk_widget_path_iter_set_object_name (path, -1, selector);

  context = gtk_style_context_new ();
  gtk_style_context_set_path (context, path);
  gtk_style_context_set_parent (context, parent);
  /* Unfortunately, we have to explicitly set the state again here for it to take effect */
  gtk_style_context_set_state (context, gtk_widget_path_iter_get_state (path, -1));
  gtk_widget_path_unref (path);

  return context;
}

static void
draw_style_common (GtkStyleContext *context,
                   cairo_t         *cr,
                   gint             x,
                   gint             y,
                   gint             width,
                   gint             height,
                   gint            *contents_x,
                   gint            *contents_y,
                   gint            *contents_width,
                   gint            *contents_height)
{
  GtkBorder margin, border, padding;
  int min_width, min_height;

  gtk_style_context_get_margin (context, gtk_style_context_get_state (context), &margin);
  gtk_style_context_get_border (context, gtk_style_context_get_state (context), &border);
  gtk_style_context_get_padding (context, gtk_style_context_get_state (context), &padding);

  gtk_style_context_get (context, gtk_style_context_get_state (context),
                         "min-width", &min_width,
                         "min-height", &min_height,
                         NULL);
  x += margin.left;
  y += margin.top;
  width -= margin.left + margin.right;
  height -= margin.top + margin.bottom;

  width = MAX (width, min_width);
  height = MAX (height, min_height);

  gtk_render_background (context, cr, x, y, width, height);
  gtk_render_frame (context, cr, x, y, width, height);

  if (contents_x)
    *contents_x = x + border.left + padding.left;
  if (contents_y)
    *contents_y = y + border.top + padding.top;
  if (contents_width)
    *contents_width = width - border.left - border.right - padding.left - padding.right;
  if (contents_height)
    *contents_height = height - border.top - border.bottom - padding.top - padding.bottom;
}

static void
query_size (GtkStyleContext *context,
            gint            *width,
            gint            *height)
{
  GtkBorder margin, border, padding;
  int min_width, min_height;

  gtk_style_context_get_margin (context, gtk_style_context_get_state (context), &margin);
  gtk_style_context_get_border (context, gtk_style_context_get_state (context), &border);
  gtk_style_context_get_padding (context, gtk_style_context_get_state (context), &padding);

  gtk_style_context_get (context, gtk_style_context_get_state (context),
                         "min-width", &min_width,
                         "min-height", &min_height,
                         NULL);

  min_width += margin.left + margin.right + border.left + border.right + padding.left + padding.right;
  min_height += margin.top + margin.bottom + border.top + border.bottom + padding.top + padding.bottom;

  *width = MAX (*width, min_width);
  *height = MAX (*height, min_height);
}

static void
draw_radio (GtkWidget     *widget,
            cairo_t       *cr,
            gint           x,
            gint           y,
            GtkStateFlags  state)
{
  GtkStyleContext *button_context, *check_context;
  gint contents_x, contents_y, contents_width, contents_height;
  gint width = 0, height = 0;

  /* This information is taken from the GtkRadioButton docs, see "CSS nodes" */
  button_context = get_style (NULL, "radiobutton");
  check_context = get_style (button_context, "radio");

  gtk_style_context_set_state (check_context, state);

  query_size (button_context, &width, &height);
  query_size (check_context, &width, &height);

  draw_style_common (button_context, cr, x, y, width, height, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  draw_style_common (check_context, cr, x, y, width, height,
                     &contents_x, &contents_y, &contents_width, &contents_height);
  gtk_render_option (check_context, cr, contents_x, contents_y, contents_width, contents_height);

  g_object_unref (check_context);
  g_object_unref (button_context);

}

static gboolean
draw_cb (GtkWidget *widget,
         cairo_t   *cr)
{
  draw_radio (widget, cr, 10, 10, GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL);
  draw_radio (widget, cr, 50, 50, GTK_STATE_FLAG_CHECKED);
  draw_radio (widget, cr, 100, 100, GTK_STATE_FLAG_INCONSISTENT);
  draw_radio (widget, cr, 150, 150, GTK_STATE_FLAG_INSENSITIVE);

  return FALSE;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *box, *window, *da;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  box = gtk_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 10);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box);

  g_signal_connect (box, "draw", G_CALLBACK (draw_cb), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  gtk_main ();

  return 0;
}
```